# Jquery TokenInput Pre-populate based on Selected option in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I need to pre-populate textfields that's using jquery tokeninput based on what is populated from a readonly field right next to it. This readonly text field is populated based on the user's selection from a dropdown. I'm at a standstill as to best way to achieve this. Basically need to copy the value from the textfield (name=hndarea) to the dropdown (name=selarea) right next to it which is not using tokeninput. The other ones are both text fields, one readonly (hndManager1) and the other one (name=txtManager1) not read only  using tokeninput. The user could change what's in the non-readonly textfield and dropdown if they wanted.

loc.js file

```
    function setLocDropdown_other() {
    var strval = $("#selPin").val();
    if (strval != '') {
    var $select = $('#selLocation')
    $select.empty();
    $select.append('<option value="" selected> --Please select--</option>');
    getdropdowndata('/cfc/LocMatrix.cfc?method=getLocJson&Pin=' + strval,$select,'',strval)

    }
}

function getLocInfo(obj)
{
    var $Pin = $("#selPin").val();
    var $Loc = $("#selLocation").val().split("~");

     $.ajax({
        url: "/cfc/LocMatrix.cfc?method=LocMatrixDetailsJson&Pin=" + $Pin + '&Location='+ $Loc[0],
        dataType: "json",
        maxrow: 1,
        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
        success: function (data) {
             //map columns to names
            $('#hndVP').val('')
            $('#hndManager1').val('')
            var columnMap = {}
            for (var i = 0; i < data.COLUMNS.length; i++) {
                columnMap[data.COLUMNS[i]] = i    
            }

             for (var i = 0; i < data.DATA.length; i++) {
             $('#trChangeValue').show() 
             $('#hndarea').val(data.DATA[i][columnMap.area])
             $('#hndarea').show()
             if (data.DATA[i][columnMap.VP_E] != null) {$('#hndVP').val(data.DATA[i][columnMap.VP_E])}
             $('#hndVP').show()
             if (data.DATA[i][columnMap.Loc_MGR_E1] != null) {$('#hndManager1').val(data.DATA[i][columnMap.Loc_MGR_E1])}
             $('#hnManager1').show()
        }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

page.cfm

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
//autocomplete using tokeInput....      
    $("#txtVP").tokenInput("/cfc/users.cfc?method=userAutoCompleteJSON", {
            theme: "vweb",
            tokenLimit: 1,
            queryParam: "exchUsername",
            tokenFormatter: function(item){
                return "<li><p>" + item.id + "</p></li>"
            }

        });
        $("#txtManager1").tokenInput("/cfc/users.cfc?method=userAutoCompleteJSON", {
            theme: "vweb",
            tokenLimit: 1,
            queryParam: "exchUsername",
            tokenFormatter: function(item){
                return "<li><p>" + item.id + "</p></li>"
            }

        });
})
    </script>



        <cfoutput>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {  
                <cfif form.txtRequestor neq "">
                $("##txtRequestor").tokenInput("add", {id: "#form.txtRequestor#", name:"#form.txtRequestor#"});
                </cfif>
                <cfif form.txtVP neq "">
                $("##txtVP").tokenInput("add", {id: "#form.txtVP#", name:"#form.txtVP#"});
                </cfif>
                <cfif form.txtManager1 neq "">
                $("##txtManager1").tokenInput("add", {id: "#form.txtManager1#", name:"#form.txtManager1#"});
                </cfif>

            });
        </script>



        </cfoutput>


                <tr>
                <td class="tdheader">area <span class="required">*</span></td>
                <td>
                    <div style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="hndarea" name="hndarea"  class="hndFields" readonly="true" value="#form.hndarea#"></div>
                    <div style="float:left;">
                    <cfselect name="selarea" style="width:233px;">
                    <cfloop query="#getLocMatrixSelectionP['area']#">
                        <option value="#val#" <cfif form.selarea eq val>Selected</cfif>>#desc#</option>
                    </cfloop>
                    </cfselect>
                    <span id="label_selarea" class="err"></span>
                    </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>


                        <tr>
                <td class="tdheader" valign="top">VP <span class="required">*</span></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <div style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="hndVP" name="hndVP" class="hndFields" readonly="true" value="#form.hndVP#"></div>
                    <div style="float:left;"><cfinput type="text" name="txtVP" style="float:left !important;">
                   <span id="label_txtVP" class="err"></span></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdheader" valign="top">Manager 1 <span class="required">*</span></td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap">
                    <div style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="hndManager1" name="hndManager1" class="hndFields" readonly="true" value="#form.hndManager1#"></div>
                    <div style="float:left;"><cfinput type="text" name="txtManager1">
                    <span id="label_txtManager1" class="err"></span></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Seems quite similar to your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778413/copying-values-from-one-field-to-another

Comment: Is the above throwing some sort of javascript error? It is difficult tell what issue you are having without actually running the code. (Looks like that would require a lot of setup and more time than most folks have.) If you have not tried any code to populate the values yet, do that first. If you run into errors, update your question with a [*small* standalone example](http://www.sscce.org/) (if at all possible) and any error messages. Otherwise, can you please elaborate on the problem section and include any error messages.